# How do I dynamically change a Chosen select box?

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using the Google Maps API to create a list of selectable neighborhoods and using Chosen to  make it look nice. The problem that I'm having is the the Maps API doesn't get the data immediately- it does it via callback functions, which means that Chosen applies itself before the options are added, and as a result the options don't get run through Chosen (resulting in them not showing up at all).

I think in theory, it should work if I can just get the elements in the select before Chosen is applied, but I'm not sure how to do that exactly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you had a look at the section "Change / Update Events" in the documentation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did try what the docs suggest?

> Updating Chosen Dynamically
>
> If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen
>   to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "liszt:updated"
>   event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated
>   content.
>
> ```
> jQuery Version: $("#form_field").trigger("liszt:updated");
> Prototype Version: Event.fire($("form_field"), "liszt:updated");
> ```

Or, if using a newer version:

```
jQuery Version: $("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
Prototype Version: Event.fire($("form_field"), "chosen:updated");
```

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: oh I too missed that in the documentation... happens sometimes ... :)

Comment: @DanyMarcoux thanks for the comment, post has now been updated with the updated code.

Answer (score 4):

For **chosen version < 1.0** then:

```
$("#form_field").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

For **chosen version >= 1.0** then:

```
$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
```